# Как открывать/выгружать конфигурацию 1с через cmd?

Tags: 1с

Пробовал:
C:\Program Files (x86)\1cv8\8.3.13.1690\bin\1cv8.exe ENTERPRISE /S ПутьДоИнформационнойБазы /N ИмяПользователя(1С) /P Пароль(1С) /DumpConfigToFiles C:\папка но ничего не происходит, подскажите что можно сделать? Нужно для автоматизации выгрузки/загрузки конфигурации.
Еще вопрос: подскажите как выгружать конфигурацию во множество файлов, а потом получать из этого множества файлов cf файл
и если знаете как при этом еще чтоб не открывался 1с

Comment: Блин, комьюнити у 1с'а какое-то странное, никто не помогает

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй вот так:
CHCP 1251
SET cfu_file=""
SET base_dir="C:\RTTEST"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\1cv8\8.3.14.1630\bin\1cv8.exe" CONFIG /F %base_dir% /N"Администратор" /P"11111111" /DumpConfigToFiles /C:\RTTEST\123
Только у меня выгрузилось не в папку а в корень диска C в папку С

Comment: У меня такая же ситуация - не сохраняются файлы конфигурации. В ходе работы программы никаких ошибок не выдается, после отработки программы в целевой папке просто ничего не появляется.
В файле, получаемом по ключу /DumpResult, записана "1" (должен быть "0").

Если запускать с /Visible, видно стартовый экран конфигуратора, который после секунд 10-и исчезает, появляется файл, указанный в параметре /DumpResult, и все.

Строка запуска:
C:\Program Files (x86)\1cv8\8.3.15.1830\bin\1cv8.exe DESIGNER /IBName "БАЗА ДАННЫХ" /DumpCfg "C:\Users\User\Test\" /DumpResult "C:\Users\User\Test\res.txt"